# Detect if a certain Instagram post is a video using Python selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, instagram, scrape

Good afternoon,
Considering this post over here: (https://www.instagram.com/p/CN4cgcjJN8p/) I've extracted the following data with this code:

```
    likes = driver.execute_script('''return document.getElementsByClassName('Nm9Fw')[0].lastElementChild.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText''')   #extract number of likes
```

Right now, I'm trying to write a line of code to detect immediately if the post being analyzed is a video. For example, the post above should be detected as a video. However, after inspecting the HTML code I'm unsure about how to do that. The idea would be something on the lines of:

is_video = driver.execute_script(''' '''')  #true/false

I'm not entirely sure how to retrieve this information, because the others fields can be easily retrieved by checking the class with the name 'X' or with the text 'Y', but I'm not sure about this one.

How can this information be detected?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the classes _97aPb or wKWK0 hold the content. If there is a video the child has no class. Check for getAttribute("class") of the child.

I think there is a lot of complexity introduced to this though with multi-image posts and checking if each child is a video but idk if that applies to your use case.

Edit: I was wrong getAttribute will notFoundException, instead use .classList and check the length.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Matthew! I did check the child class but I keep stumbling upon NotFoundException... Multi-image posts are not a problem in this case.

Comment: @Dastru I was wrong getAttribute will notFoundException, instead use .classList and check the length. I have edited my response, I think that should work.